# Laravel chamar variavel

Tags: laravel

sou novo no laravel e estou tentando chamar a variavel igual vi no video aula porem continua dando erro 
controle

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SiteController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        $teste1 = 1;
        $bs = 12;
        return view('site.Home.index', ['teste'=>$teste1] );
    }
}
```

aonde chamo

```
 @extends('/site.Templede.templede1')
@section('title')
 teste
@endsection

@section('body')
{{$teste1}}
ss
@endsection

@section('foot')
    footer
@endsection
```

erro
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: qual o erro?...

Comment: da variável indefinida

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na verdade sua variável não se chama `$teste1` em sua View. Você está passando ela como `teste`. Isso significa que você tem que recuperá-la como `$teste`.

A linha que você passa a variável é essa: `return view('site.Home.index', ['teste'=>$teste1] );`. Aqui você setou o nome da variável `$teste1` como `teste`.

Basta trocar `{{$teste1}}` por `{{$teste}}` na sua View.

Comment: nossa mano vlw foi aquio